# Set up a pause/resume-able timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

Is there a way to create a "timer"(or stopwatch) class, that the timers created using this class can be paused and resumed on triggering an event, e.g. clicking a button?

I tried to create the class and create timer objects using it, but the timer cannot be paused once it starts.

My attempt on creating this class:

```
class countdown {
    constructor(min, sec) {
        this.mins = min;
        this.secs = sec;
        this.handler = 0;
    }

    static setTimer(x,minfield,secfield) {
        this.handler = setTimeout(() => {
            if (x.mins == 0 && x.secs == 0) {
                clearTimeout();
            } else {
                if (x.secs == 0) {
                    x.mins -= 1;
                    x.secs = 59;
                } else {
                    x.secs -= 1;
                }
            }

            this.updateTimer(x,minfield,secfield);
            this.setTimer(x,minfield,secfield)
        }, 1000)
    }

    static updateTimer(x,minfield, secfield){
        document.getElementById(minfield).innerHTML = x.mins;
        document.getElementById(secfield).innerHTML = x.secs;
    }

    static stopTimer(x,minfield,secfield) {
        // document.getElementById(minfield).innerHTML = x.mins;
        // document.getElementById(secfield).innerHTML = x.secs;
        clearTimeout(x.handler);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    let countdown1 = new countdown(15,0);
    let countdown_act = false;
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener( 'click', () => {
            if (!countdown_act) {
                countdown.setTimer(countdown1, 'ctdwn-mins', 'ctdwn-secs');
                countdown_act = true;
            } else {
                countdown.stopTimer(countdown1, 'ctdwn-mins', 'ctdwn-secs');
                countdown_act = false;
            }
            console.log(countdown_act);
        }
    )
```

The countdown_act flag is used for indicating the state of the timer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for any of your methods to be `static`. Also, it's much simpler and easier to use if you just record seconds and then calculate minutes when you need the output. As a standard, capitalize the name of classes. Finally, you're probably looking for `setInterval`, not timeout.

Think of a real-world timer. You can set it, start it, pause it, and stop it. Stopping a timer is really just restarting it and pausing it, and it's set upon creation, so let's make a `Timer` with `start`, `pause`, `set` and `stop` or `reset`. This still behaves the same way as yours in the background by using a 1s timeout, but it's a lot cleaner and easier for someone reading your code to understand:

```
class Timer {
    constructor(seconds, callback) {
        this.originalTime = seconds;
        this.remainingTime = seconds;
        this.timeout = null;
        this.callback = callback; // This is what the timer does when it ends
    }

    start() {
        this.timeout = setInterval(() => {
            this.remainingTime -= 1; // Remove a second from the timer
            if(this.remainingTime === 0) {
                this.callback(); // Run the callback function
                this.stop(); // Stop the timer to prevent it from counting into the negatives
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    pause() {
        clearInterval(this.timeout);
    }

    stop() {
        this.pause();
        this.remainingTime = this.originalTime; // Reset the time
    }

    setTime(seconds) {
        this.originalTime = seconds; // Set a new time
        this.stop(); // Have to restart the timer to account for the new time
    }

    get remaining() {
        return {
            seconds: this.remainingTime % 60,
            minutes: Math.floor(this.remainingTime / 60)
        }
    }
}
```